# What are the most popular techniques of proving inequalities?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation, book-recommendation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I know some of it, but I would like to learn other ones. I think this question is useful, as it will be helpful for other beginners.
Such as: uvw, AM GM, Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, Jensen inequality. Could you please add something? Maybe books containing it?

Comment: You might be interested in "The Cauchy-Schwartz Master Class" by Stelle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are also:

1. TL (The Tangent Line Method)
2. SOS (Sum of Squares)
3. Schur (Inequalities like the Schur's inequalities)
4. SS (SOS-Schur metod)
5. Muirhead (Muirhead inequalities)
6. Karamata
7. Rearragement
8. Chebyshov
9. Holder
10. Bacteria (undefined coefficients method)
11. Discriminant
12. The $uvw$'s technique (it's not the $uvw$ method)
13. Minkowski (triangle inequality)
14. Bernoulli
15. LM ( Lagrange Multipliers method)
16. EV (The Vasc's Equal Variables Method)
17. RCF, LCF (the Vasc's Right Convex Function Method and Left Convex Function Method)
18. Zhaobin (about half convex- half concave function)
19. prR (for the geometric inequalities proofs)
20. BW (the Buffalo Way method)

and more.

A very good book it's "Algebraic inequalities, old and new methods", Gil, 2006 by Vasile Cirtoaje.

Also, thanks to Jose Brox, there is the beautiful Vasc's last book about inequalities, which he published in 2015.

The example, how the Bacteria method helps to find a proof of the very hard inequality.

Let $a\geq0$, $b\geq0$ and $c\geq0$ such that $a+b+c=3$. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{8+a^2b}+\frac{1}{8+b^2c}+\frac{1}{8+c^2a}\geq\frac{1}{3}.$$ 
This inequality is ninth degree.

Now, we'll reduce this degree.

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8+a^2b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+kb+mc)^2}{(a+kb+mc)^2(8+a^2b)}\geq\frac{(1+k+m)^2(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+kb+mc)^2(8+a^2b)}.$$
We'll choose values of $k$ and $m$ ( they are our bacteria) such that the inequality 
$$\frac{(1+k+m)^2(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+kb+mc)^2(8+a^2b)}\geq\frac{1}{3}$$ would be true.

Since the equality in the starting inequality occurs for $a=b=c=1$ and again for

$(a,b,c)=(1,0,2)$ and for cyclic permutations of the last, we get the following system:
$$\frac{a+kb+mc}{(a+kb+mc)^2(8+a^2b)}=\frac{b+kc+ma}{(b+kc+ma)^2(8+b^2c)}= \frac{c+ka+mb}{(c+ka+mb)^2(8+c^2a)}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{(a+kb+mc)(8+a^2b)}=\frac{1}{(b+kc+ma)(8+b^2c)}= \frac{1}{(c+ka+mb)(8+c^2a)},$$ which is obviously true for $a=b=c=1$.

But for $(a,b,c)=(1,0,2)$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{8(1+2m)}=\frac{1}{8(2k+m)}= \frac{1}{12(2+k)},$$
which gives $k=\frac{8}{5}$, $m=\frac{11}{5}$ and we can write:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{8+a^2b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(5a+8b+11c)^2}{(5a+8b+11c)^2(8+a^2b)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a+8b+11c)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a+8b+11c)^2(8+a^2b)}=\frac{576(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a+8b+11c)^2(8+a^2b)}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{576(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a+8b+11c)^2(8+a^2b)}\geq\frac{1}{3},$$ which is fifth degree and the rest is smooth.

Comment: What exactly is the bacterium method, and why is it different from Lagrange's?

Comment: @Jose Brox This method goes with CS or Holder. I am ready to give an example, how it works.

Comment: An example would be cool! Thanks

Comment: Btw, there is a new (2015) book by Cirtoaje called *Mathematical Inequalities*, in 4 volumes!

Comment: Yes, it's the best book! I am posting now the example for the B method. Wait please.

Comment: Thanks, this one is VERY helpful. I won't waste it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for the example. Do you know where the name "bacterium" comes from? (btw, the plural of "bacterium" would be "bacteria")

Comment: @Jose Brox One of my pupils said so in Hebrew and I like it. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @ MichaelRozenberg : Please give us some inequalities can solve (not too basic or easy) by discriminant.

Comment: @Trần Văn Lâm Try the following. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ be real numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\geq0.$ Prove that: $((b+c)x+(c+a)y+(a+b)z)^2\geq4(ab+ac+bc)(xy+xz+yz).$

Comment: Volume 5 of Cirtoaje's books is now available.

Answer (score 3):

The book [Inequalities](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=t1RCSP8YKt8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=George%20Polya%20Inequalities&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-h5nRiJ_dAhVEHZAKHeKYApgQ6wEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=George%20Polya%20Inequalities&f=false) by Por G. H. Hardy, J. E. Littlewood, G. Pólya.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the elementary triangle inequality, and Radon's inequality (which is sometimes called Titu's lemma in the Olympiad context, although Radon's is both older and stronger).

In the Olympiad problems context there are lots of books and lecture notes about this subject. You have for example *Secrets in inequalities* by Hung (in two volumes), *A brief introduction to inequalities* by Lugo, *A is lesser than B* by Kedlaya, *Basics of olympiad inequalities* by Riasat, and *Olympiad inequalities* by Mildorf.

Comment: I think all ideas from these books there are in the beautiful Vasc's last book.