# Important Olympiad-inequalities

Tags: inequality, contest-math, big-list

As an olympiad-participant, I've had to solve numerous inequalities; some easy ones and some very difficult ones. Inequalities might appear in every Olympiad discipline (Number theory, Algebra, Geometry and Combinatorics) and usually require previous manipulations, which makes them even harder to solve...

Some time ago, someone told me that

> *Solving inequalities is kind of applying the same hundred tricks again and again*

And in fact, knowledge and experience play a fundamental role when it comes to proving/solving inequalities, rather than instinct.

This is the reason why I wanted to gather the most important Olympiad-inequalities such as

1. AM-GM (and the weighted one)
2. Cauchy-Schwarz
3. Jensen

...

Could you suggest some more?

---

This question was inspired by the fantastic contributions of @Michael Rozenberg on inequalities.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, I know that the question you've linked might look similar to mine; however, I wanted to emphasize the fact that I'm looking for $\mathbf{olympiad}$ inequalities, which has nothing to do with the inequalities you might require for the maths-degree for instance...

Comment: All these they are Olimpiad inequalities. I think these themes they are same. Remember, there is also IMC.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg What do you mean by IMC?

Comment: See here: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Essential reading:

[Olympiad Inequalities, Thomas J. Mildorf](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf)

All useful inequalities are clearly listed and explaind on the first few pages. Mildorf calls them **"The Standard Dozen"**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** If you look for a good book, here is my favorite one:

[image]

The book covers in extensive detail the following topics:

[image]

[image]

Also a fine reading:

[A Brief Introduction to Olympiad Inequalities](http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Ineq/en.pdf), Evan Chen

Comment: While the reference you provide might be useful, displaying text-as-images makes your answer inaccessible to screenreaders, and hampers the searchability of your answer.  It would be preferable if you could summarize (in text) the major important results.

Answer (score 9):

I did not find a link, but I wrote about this theme already.

I'll write something again.

There are many methods:

1. Cauchy-Schwarz (C-S)
2. AM-GM
3. Holder
4. Jensen
5. Minkowski
6. Maclaurin
7. Rearrangement
8. Chebyshov
9. Muirhead
10. Karamata
11. Lagrange multipliers
12. Buffalo Way (BW)
13. Contradiction
14. Tangent Line method
15. Schur
16. Sum Of Squares (SOS)
17. Schur-SOS method (S-S)
18. Bernoulli
19. Bacteria
20. RCF, LCF, HCF (with half convex, half concave functions) by V.Cirtoaje
21. E-V Method by  V.Cirtoaje
22. uvw
23. Inequalities like Schur
24. pRr method for the geometric inequalities

and more.

In my opinion, the best book it's the inequalities forum in the AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities

Just read it!

Also, there is the last book by Vasile Cirtoaje (2018) and his papers.

An example for using pRr.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be sides-lengths of a triangle. Prove that:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-a^2b-a^2c-b^2a-b^2c-c^2a-c^2b+3abc\geq0.$$

Proof:

It's $$R\geq2r,$$ which is obvious.

Actually, the inequality $$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\geq0$$ is true for all non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ and named as the Schur's inequality.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903914/what-are-the-most-popular-techniques-of-proving-inequalities), which was also written by OP

Comment: This is the link. Thank you!

Comment: Not that it's very important, but you're missing a dot after 16 which has kind of given a bad look to the list. :P Also, what is the pRr method? I googled it but ended up with results in biology which I don't think are very relevant. It's hard to find relevant results about some of the acronyms you used on Google. Don't even get me started on "Bacteria". :P

Comment: @stressed out I added something. See now. About Bacteria see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903914

Comment: Thank you. So, pRr method is about the relations among the perimeter, inscribed and circumscribed circles of a triangle?

Comment: @stressed out Yes, of course! But it's a semi-perimeter. Sometimes it's very useful.