# $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}} \leq \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}.$ explaination

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are non-negative numbers such that: $a+b+c=3$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}} \leq \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Solution:

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\left(\sum _{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}} \right)^2 =\left(\sum _{cyc}\sqrt{(c+a).\frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\right)^2\leq \left[\sum_{cyc}(c+a)\right]\left[\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c)}\right]$$
$$=\frac{4\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}=\frac{4\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)}{\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)-abc}\leq \frac{4\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)}{\frac{8}{9}\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)}=\frac{9}{2}.$$

So we have q.e.d.

But my question is how can they find this:$$\left(\sum _{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}} \right)^2 =\left(\sum _{cyc}\sqrt{(c+a).\frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\right)^2\leq \left[\sum_{cyc}(c+a)\right]\left[\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}\right]$$

By using:$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}=\sqrt{(a+c).\frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c)}}$$

How can they know that?

Comment: It seems that this is your first time using internet so let me tell you that writing in ALLCAPS in internet is the equivalent of yelling. Please, don't yell at us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}$ is cyclic and if we want to get something symmetric so the first idea is to try to work with $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c)},$ which gives your C-S.

In the general there is a Bacteria's method which sometimes helps if the equality occurs  in another points (or closed to another point) not only for $a=b=c$.

In your inequality it's not so and it's enough to think about symmetrization.

Comment: But how can the find the $(a+c)$ and why don't they find an another things like $a^2+bc, a^2+b^2+c^2,...$. Thank you a lots!

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát  $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{(*a+b)(a+c)}$ is symmetric. See please better my post.  With this trick there are another solutions, of course, but they are not so nice. There is a nice solution by Jensen.

Comment: Where can I find the Bacteria's method? Thank a lots!!!

Comment: About Bacteria see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903914/what-are-the-most-popular-techniques-of-proving-inequalities

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's the wrong statement. The application of CS is actually

$$\left(\sum _{cyc}\sqrt{(c+a).\frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\right)^2\leq \left[\sum_{cyc}(c+a)\right]\left[\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(a+b)\color{red}{(a+c)}}\right]$$

To get to the next line, observe that $\sum (c+a) = 2 \sum a$ and $\sum \frac{a}{(a+b)(a+c) } = \sum \frac{ ab+ac}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) } = \frac{ 2(\sum ab)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$. Thus

$$\left[\sum_{cyc}(c+a)\right]\left[\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(a+b)\color{red}{(a+c)}}\right]= \frac{4\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)}{\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)-abc}$$

annd the rest of the proof is fine.

Comment: Actually that is my mistake in writting, can you explain it please? Thank you!

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát Ah, if that was a typo on your end, then Michael's post dives into that. There's much to learn from his experience of solving inequalities.